# How can I make phone numbers pretty/user friendly when their existing formats are inconsistent?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, formatting

I'm binding a textbox to a member of a class, and I need to tweak the appearance of the phone number so that it's easier to read (the user doesn't want to see values such as "1234567890" or "+01234567890"). So, I've got this code:

```
var bindingPhone = new Binding("Text", platypusInfo, "Phone1", true);
bindingPhone.Format += phoneBinding_Format;
textBoxPhoneNum1.DataBindings.Add(bindingPhone);

...

private void phoneBinding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e) {
    e.Value = ??How can I deal with this??
}
```

But the phone values, although *usually* either "NNNNNNNNNN" (such as "1234567890") or "+NNNNNNNNNNN" (such as "+01234567890") can also appear in a number of other permutations, such as:

```
 (NN) NNNN NNNN
++NNNNNNNNNNNNN
+NNNNNNNNNNNNN
+NN NNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Is there anything I can do in phoneBinding_Format() that will make these phone numbers easier to read without breaking them into nonsensical parts, such as "43-4859-4365" instead of "434-859-4365"?

### UPDATE

Due to these factors:

1) I'm working on several projects simultaneously and need to get back to another one
2) Our two most common formats comprise the lion's share of our phone numbers
3) This is just a "nice feature" not a "must-have" feature

...I've settled on the following for now, based on a Jon Skeet answer:

```
private void phoneBinding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    const int UK_PHONE_LEN = 9;                     // +NNNNNNNN 
     const int US_PHONE_FORMAT_LEN = 10;             // NNNNNNNNNN
    const int COMMON_INTERNATIONAL_FORMAT_LEN = 12; //+NNNNNNNNNNN 

    string phone;
    string area;
    string major;
    string minor;
    string intl_firstsegment;
    string intl_secondsegment;
    string intl_thirdsegment;
    string intl_fourthsegment;
    string intl_fifthsegment;

    if (e.Value.ToString().Length == US_PHONE_FORMAT_LEN)
    {
        phone = e.Value.ToString();
        area = phone.Substring(0, 3);
        major = phone.Substring(3, 3);
        minor = phone.Substring(6);
        e.Value = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", area, major, minor); 
    } 
else if ((e.Value.ToString().Length == UK_PHONE_LEN) && (e.Value.ToString()[0] == '+')) {
    phone = e.Value.ToString();
    intl_firstsegment = phone.Substring(0, 2);
    intl_secondsegment = phone.Substring(2, 3);
    intl_thirdsegment = phone.Substring(5);
    e.Value = string.Format("+{0}-{1}-{2}", intl_firstsegment, intl_secondsegment, intl_thirdsegment);
} 
else if ((e.Value.ToString().Length == COMMON_INTERNATIONAL_PHONE_LEN) && (e.Value.ToString()[0] == '+')) 
    {
        phone = e.Value.ToString();
        intl_firstsegment = phone.Substring(0, 2);
        intl_secondsegment = phone.Substring(2, 2);
        intl_thirdsegment = phone.Substring(4, 3);
        intl_fourthsegment = phone.Substring(7, 2);
        intl_fifthsegment = phone.Substring(9);
        e.Value = string.Format("+{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}", intl_firstsegment, intl_secondsegment, intl_thirdsegment, intl_fourthsegment, intl_fifthsegment);
    }
}
```

BTW, an interesting thing happened on the way to breakpoint nirvana: I originally had these tests (1st character is a plus sign and length is the expected) reversed, and got: *System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.*

Reversing the condition so that length was checked first (which naturally doesn't fail when length is 0/string is empty) fixed it (since then no attempt is made to access char 0).

Comment: Unfortunately "nonsensical" can be a relative term. For example, in some countries, "43-3859-3465" is a perfectly valid phone number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google's [LibPhoneNumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) could be just what you need if you want to support international phone numbers in addition to US (and Canadian, which are 100% compatible with US) numbers.

> Google's common Java, C++ and Javascript library for parsing, formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers. The Java version is optimized for running on smartphones, and is used by the Android framework since 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

Using it from C#:

http://blog.thekieners.com/2011/06/06/using-googles-libphonenumber-in-microsoft-net-with-c/

C# port

https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would be to just strip out all non-numeric characters and whitespace from the string before applying your formatting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h.aspx

Comment: Hopefully nobody enters 1-800-SOLIDCODE.  I would buy non-Alphanumeric characters :-)

Comment: @EricJ: Well, that's up to the design to determine if that case needs to be handled. If so, I'd just change my regex or whatever to only strip out non-alpha-numberic characters.

Comment: The non-numeric characters and whilespace may be required for determining the country/scheme of the phone numbers.  If you need to support all international numbers and not just one country's schema anyway.

Comment: Non-numeric characters should not be needed as far as I'm aware, though the "+" I guess could be useful to disambiguate some cases where it's unclear whether the # is entered with or without a country prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting code snippet [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1487.htm). Can be used to pretty-up phone numbers before displaying them.

```
Input: xxxxxxxxxx or xxx-xxx-xxxx or (xxx) xxx-xxxx, Output: (xxx) xxx-xxxx
```

**Code**:

```
private string formatPhoneNumber(string number) {
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex pattern = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\\(?([1-9]\\d{2})\\)?\\D*?([1-9]\\d{2})\\D*?(\\d{4})$");
    Match re = Regex.Match(number, pattern.ToString());
    return "(" + Convert.ToString(re.Groups[1]) + ") " + Convert.ToString(re.Groups[2]) + "-" + Convert.ToString(re.Groups[3]);
}
```

Comment: What does this interesting snippet do?  Without explanation, the answer is not very useful...

Comment: Thanks for providing clarification... What if the number is in Germany, where the format could be +49-89-123456 or +49-45563-1234

Comment: For the countries the OP wants to support, he will have to add his own routine, which can parse that particular country's number.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally specify that only numeric phone numbers are allowed (meaning the user may not enter phone numbers like 1-800-FLOWERS) and then strip all non numeric characters, before formatting.

Comment: Hopefully nobody enters 1-800-FLOWERS

Comment: @EricJ. haha, good point.  I personally hate the phone numbers that use words that are longer than the actually numbers that should be entered.  It infuriates me.

Comment: Yes but good 800 numbers are hard to come by :-)  Change your answer to non-Alphanumeric and it will work.

Comment: @EricJ. I would say that it is usually an OK stipulation to have the user enter only numeric values.  Those 800 numbers have numeric values, you are just asking for trouble otherwise.

Comment: @Stefan: I can't specify/regulate what the user's enter as phone numbers or how they are stored in the DB; these values I'm dealing with are already in the DB and have been/are being placed there by legacy apps.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm getting is that you have numbers stored in ten-digit character format ("1234567890"), without formatting, but now you need to add formatting to make the number more readable without making the number nonsensical for the country the number is used in. As different countries/regions have different default formats for numbers, the NANPA system of (ACD) COX-SUBS for area code, central office and subscriber doesn't always apply.

My suggestion would be to maintain a table or dictionary of phone number masks, then use a MaskedTextBox and bind not only the number, but the mask, to data in the contact object.

For instance, phone mask ID 1 might be for NANPA numbers: "000-000-0000". Phone mask ID 2 might be for London-metro numbers and would be "\000 0000 0000" (the leading digit is always a zero, and should be omitted when calling from outside the country). ID 3 might be for French phone numbers: "00 00 00 00 00". You can specify a "get-only" property on the object that will provide the actual mask string to the TextBox, and bind a different control (a drop-down maybe) that the user can choose to display the number in the correct format (which you can save for later use with that contact). Most of the time you'll be able to guess based on country, but this isn't always the case.

Understand that you will need a LOT of masks, and they aren't always ten digits. While the NANPA system is relatively consistent, UK phone numbers are a mess; geographic area codes are variable-length, and the total number can be ten or eleven digits, so there are six different masks just for UK numbers based on geographic area code. In Mexico, area codes can be two or three digits, and the total number is ten digits. French phone numbers are ten digits in groups of two. In addition, the actual combination of digits to be dialed depends on where you're calling from; if the call is always from the US, many European number systems drop their leading zero used for in-country calls and you instead dial the country code.